# Multiple While loops working togther at once - MATLAB GUI

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing

I developed a MATLAB GUI with multiple push buttons exist. Each push button begins an execution of an infinite loop. When I press a push button the while loop executes fine, but when I press the next push button, the first stops and the next starts, What I need is for all while loops can work simultaneously. I know there is a toolbox in MATLAB called Parallel Computing Toolbox, but i cant figure out how can I use it. Also tried searching for multi-threading tech's but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
% --- Executes on button press in StartCam1.
function StartCam1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
axes(handles.axes1);
CamURL = 'http://192.168.1.2:80/jpg/image.jpg?timestamp='
Image  = imread(CamURL);
Frame = image(Image);

while(1)
   Image  = imread(CamURL);
   set(Frame,'CData',Image);
   drawnow;
end

% --- Executes on button press in StartCam2.
function StartCam2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
axes(handles.axes2);
CamURL = 'http://192.168.1.3:80/jpg/image.jpg?timestamp='
Image  = imread(CamURL);
Frame = image(Image);

while(1)
  Image  = imread(CamURL);
  set(Frame,'CData',Image);
  drawnow;
end
```

Comment: Why do you need such behaviour? Chances are there's a better way to accomplish it than two concurrent infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of independent 'while' loops, think about one large one that optionally performs many sub-functions.

```
% Pseudocode:
while !do_exit
    if (button1_active)
        % Do some things
    done
    if (button2_active)
        % Do some different things
    done
end
```

Run this loop all the time, starting when you open the GUI, and exiting when the GUI closes.

Alternately, think about using Timers.  When you push a button, start a timer, which will will execute a callback function, which should perform a single iteration of your while loop.  Use one timer per button, so they can be independently started and stopped.  This has the added advantage of being able to control the execution rate.

EDIT: Going with the timer approach, and listing only one camera.  The other is the same.

```
% GUI Init
function gui_init
axes(handles.axes1);
handles.CamURL1 = 'http://192.168.1.2:80/jpg/image.jpg?timestamp='
Image  = imread(CamURL);
handles.frame1 = image(Image);
guidata(hObject, handles)

% --- Executes on Cam1 timer expiry
function Cam1_NextFrame_Callback(hObject, handles)
Image  = imread(handles.CamURL1);
set(handles.frame1,'CData',Image);
drawnow;

% --- Executes on button press in StartCam1.
function StartCam1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

handles.timer1 = timer(...
  'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...   % Run timer repeatedly
  'Period', 1, ...                % Initial period is 1 sec.
  'TimerFcn', {@Cam1_NextFrame_Callback, hObject, handles}); % Specify callback timer.

start(handles.timer1);
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Note: `handles` is the guidata object attached to this GUI.  It appears you're already using it (for axes1), so we'll store the rest of the persistent GUI stuff there.   Your persistent-data approach may be different.  Adjust as necessary.  `gui_init` is pseudocode.  The contents have to go wherever you first create your GUI, either in bare MATLAB code or in the GUIDE-created GUI init placeholder.

Note 2: If you cut-and-paste for camera2, you'll notice that the code is almost identical.  Consider storing some of these handle variables as arrays, and then you'll be able to reuse the timer callback function.  Just pass in the camera index.

Comment: Good Thinking. I edited the question with a code snip, how can I apply your logic to this cod snip ?

Comment: So, this same code snip applies for Cam2 and I am good to go ?. Another Thing what about the global while loop approach, how can i go around that ? and Thanks btw